# Check if a user is a memberOf an AD group using VB Script

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, memberof

I have the following script to determine whether the current user is a part of a pre-determined group. I can get the correct username using the `ADSystemInfo`, but the `objGroup.IsMember` function always returns true. Even if there is no Group to check.

I'm using Internet Explorer 11 and the website (IIS 8.5, Windows Server 2012 R2) is set to authenticate users, ie. Anonymous Authentication is disabled.

```
<%   
  function IsAMemberOf(sGroupDN)
    IsAMemberOf = "N"
    on error resume next
    dim objGroup, objADSysInfo, strUserDN
   
    'https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198776.aspx
    Set objADSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & sGroupDN & ",OU=MyTown,OU=MyDomain,DC=LOCAL")
    if not IsEmpty(objGroup) then
      if objGroup.IsMember("LDAP://" & objADSysInfo.UserName)Then
        ' The user is in the group so we can do things
        'response.write(Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER") & " is a member of " & sGroupDN & "<br>")
        IsAMemberOf = "Y"
      end if
    end if

    set objGroup = nothing
    set objADSysInfo = nothing
  end function
%>
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Step 1: remove `on error resume next` and run it again. Do you get an error? Also, you said it _always returns true_. Do you mean it always returns `"Y"`?

Comment: Also, `nil` is not a VBScript keyword. Use `Nothing` instead. Or just omit those two lines completely. They'll be disposed of when the function exits.

Comment: For whatever reason, the `objGroup.IsMember` method returns True if objGroup is Nothing.  So you probably have something wrong with the group's LDAP path (which will cause objGroup.IsMember to return Nothing.  The way you have it, you'll need to pass in "CN=TheGroupName" and assuming the rest of the LDAP path is correct it should work.  I tested it as just a VBScript--not in a browser.

Comment: @Bond. It always returns "Y".

Comment: @Tony Hinkle. It is the 'getObject' that is failing so I end up with nothing. I now use 'IsEmpty(ogjGroup)' to check and there is no error. I've also checked the search strings against the actual distinguished name in the AD and they match. I'll have to find another way. Maybe and LDAP query.

Comment: How are spaces in a OU trated? Ex. If I call my function as follows: IsAMemberOf("CN=Property & Development,OU=Property & Development")